# Setup ulimit parameter in dockerfile

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker file. Can anyone please tell me that how to add the ulimit parameter in docker file.
I tried like this:

```
RUN --ulimit nofile=262144:262144
```

But it is showing error. Can anyone please tell me how to correctly set this parameter in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set ulimits on docker containers in the dockerfile - needs to be set when running the container from the command line. Try this:

```
docker run --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 IMAGE
```

Comment: I also tried this but it freezes the API file system.

Comment: The api is probably using too many files, then. 262144 is a lot, can you decrease that number?

Comment: did you get a change to try this : https://medium.com/@muhammadtriwibowo/set-permanently-ulimit-n-open-files-in-ubuntu-4d61064429a